# Product Collection By Atttribute Code

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

I have product Attribute "Model". Now, I want those product which have model attribute from product Collection

how I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can collection by this below code :

```
protected $productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory  $productCollectionFactory

){
     $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
}

$productcollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
```

set your attribute code and value in **addAttributeToFilter()** based on your requirement.